# How to test if a file is executable by its owner ** not necessarily me **

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, permissions

This is not a duplicate question.

Assume I have

1. the full path
2. to a regular file named `target`
3. that *might* be owned by *some other user.*
4. and the environment may be stripped down (busybox with very little enabled)

**In a shell script, how can I test whether this file is executable by its owner *when I might not be its owner*?** Imagine that my program's purpose is to check if everything is set up nicely for other things to run (since the  environment may have been ruined by other users) and it's looking in a particular directory to make sure the owners of every file have permission to execute their file.

This is a professional context, not homework.

Any solution I will use needs to cover all kinds of old Linux environments that I had no hand in setting up (so they could be *missing* things you'd normally expect like `which` or some options on `find` etc).

However, this question might be useful for others who don't face that limitation so I do appreciate other solutions that require more complete or modern environments.

`[ -x "$path" ]` only tells me if ***I*** can execute it.

`ls -l "$path"` and checking if the fourth character is `x` seems too fragile: `-rwxrw-rw- 1 otheruser group 26 Jun 13 10:57 target`

`ls -F "$path"` and checking if it ends in `*` seems a little better: `target*` The one environment I tested does take into account who the actual owner is... But this does not feel like the best way...

Comment: What if the fs is mounted noexec? This will prevent a user from executing a file regardless of its permissions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639), [How to check if command exists in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7522712/608639), [Check if a file is executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10319652/608639), [How to check if a file is executable in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42633413/608639), [How to check if command is available or existant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7222674/608639), etc.

Comment: I've edited to make it clear this is not a duplicate of any of those. (My reason for ruling out `[ -x "$path" ]` was technically enough to distinguish, I think) My program is a validator and it wants to make sure the owner of each file in a directory is executable by that specific owner. I don't think groups count because I dropped user permissions on something I owned that had (my) group and other x set and I couldn't execute it. Not homework. Needs to be robust and handle all kinds of strange/old Linux environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
permissions=$(stat -c "%a" target)
permissions=$(( ${permissions: -3: 1} % 2 ))
```

[stat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/stat.1.html) gives you file permissions in octal. Then we need just the character for the owner's permissions (technically third from the right, not the first character), and then need to check if it's odd (executable in octal is the 1 bit).

If permissions is 1, it's executable by the owner. If it's 0, it's not.

Older environments might require arithmetic expressions instead:

```
permissions=$(stat -c "%a" $target)
if [ $((0$permissions & 0100)) -ne 0 ]; then
    # executable by owner
else
    # not executable by owner
fi
```

Comment: @thatotherguy, Is that taking a sub-string of val starting at `3` characters from the right end? If so, isn't the next argument the length and should that be a `1` instead of a `-2`? Or ... what am I mistaken about when it comes to that `-2`?

Comment: @user1011471, you could try testing the code yourself and verifying that it works.

Comment: @user1011471 http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#negative_length_value

Comment: Oh. "This works since Bash 4.2-alpha" In one my later edits to the OP, I mention needing to support some crazy old environments, in which case `1` would be better, right?

Comment: @user1011471, yes. I believe that the negative offset might not even work in sufficiently old versions of bash (but I could be wrong on that, I couldn't find a source to back up that feeling)

Comment: If you add `1` as an alternative that works on older machines, I'll accept this answer. It's what I ended up using.

Comment: @user1011471, changed. 1 is correct either way so it doesn't really need to be an alternative.

Comment: Another alternative would be `if (( 0$val & 0100)); then echo "executable by owner"; fi`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `find`, if you don't want to parse the output of something:

```
if find ${path} -prune -perm -u+x | grep -q ''; then
  echo "Executable by owner"
else
  echo "Not executable by owner"
fi
```

The `-perm` option let's you check if it's executable by the `user` (owner) and the `-prune` option prevents descending in to a directory if `${path}` is a directory so we can just check the given path by itself.

Answer (score 0):

`ls -l "$path"` and check the first group of permissions (owner permissions). If there is an `x` in it then the file is executable by its owner.

Comment: How do you express that (checking the first group of permissions for an x) in shell script?